# пытаюсь создать строку на сайте через django

Tags: django

```
return HttpResponse('Привет! Я ... и мне 17 лет.  <br>' , a)
```

(переменная a = случайное число от 0 до 100)
вроде ошибок нет,но выдаёт не строку и случайное число,а что-то непонятное...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: зачем-то у вас происходит лишнее перекодирование cp1251->utf8. хотя исходная строка уже в utf8.

Comment: что мне с этим делать? как убрать перекодирование? если убрать a,то всё получается... Как исправить?